# Yii Extending Request Component returns 500 error

Tags: yii, yii2

I'm trying to extend the Request component of Yii2 as our previous Yii1 project extended CHttpRequest, but all I get is a 500 error no matter what I try. My config is as follow:

```
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'class' => 'app\components\MY_HttpRequest',
        'cookieValidationKey' => '...',
    ],
    ...
],
```

Then in //components/MY_HttpRequest.php, even with an empty class that would just call the parent's method:

```
<?php

//namespace app\components;
namespace app\components\MY_HttpRequest;

use Yii;

class MY_HttpRequest extends yii\web\Request {
}
```

It displays a 500 error, so I can't really debug this as I don't have any feedback. I searched on Google how to extend the Request component but all I found was a question on how to extend the [Response component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912272/yii-2-0-how-to-extend-core-classes), and I'm already using that method with no success.

There are no details about the error (Only using example.com as example):
[image]

Moreover, if I change this line like such:

```
'class' => 'app\components\MY_HttpRequestaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
```

I get an error that the file is not found, so I know the file is being loaded.

Comment: error 500 for what  ? .. show the complete error message

Comment: A typical 500 server error, I don't have any details, but I added a screenshot if this can somehow help

Comment: Can you show all content of `components/MY_HttpRequest.php` file?

Comment: Sure can! Just did :)

Comment: Arrgh!! I got it! forgot a simple tiny backslash I had missed! "extends \yii\web\Request", not "extends yii\web\Request"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out I had just forgotten a tiny backslash in my "extend" statement.

```
class MY_HttpRequest extends yii\web\Request
```

Should have been

```
class MY_HttpRequest extends \yii\web\Request
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your class and file name to `MYHttpRequest` and it will be work

```
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'class' => 'app\components\MYHttpRequest',
        'cookieValidationKey' => '...',
    ],
]
```

And components/MYHttpRequest.php

```
namespace app\components;

class MYHttpRequest extends \yii\web\Request {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion friend, however I had already tried that and it didn't work :/

Comment: i hope your components/MYHttpRequest.php file have namespace like `namespace app\components;` ?

Comment: I copied your code, replace "_" symbol, and problem solved for me

Comment: Tried namespace app\components; AND namespace app\components\MYHttpRequest; still doesn't want to work... I don't get it

Comment: I got it friend! I rewrote another class in a new blank project and it was just a typo! I wrote "extends yii\web\Request" instead of "extends \yii\web\Request"